# Trying to make a date class that advances the date by one when implemented

Tags: java, eclipse, class

I don't want to worry about leap years but I am worrying about if what I have as a foundation is correct.

import javax.swing.Spring;

```
public class Date 
{

    /**
     * A variable to hold the day value
     */
    private int day;

    /**
     * A variable to hold the month value
     */
    private int month;

    /**
     * A variable to hold the year value
     */
    private int year;

    /**
     * the date in the form m/d/yyyy
     */
    private String stringDate;

    /**
     * To figure out which month it is
     */
    private boolean isThirtyDays, isThirtyOneDays, isTwentyEightDays;

    /**
     * advances the date by one day based on the month
     */
    private void advance()
    {

        if(month == 9 || month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 11)
        {
            if(day == 30)
            {
                month++;
                day = 1;
            }

            else
                day++;
        }

        if(month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8
                || month == 10 || month == 12)
        {
            if(day == 31)

            {
                month++;
                day = 1;

                if(month == 12)

                {
                    month = 1;
                    day = 1;
                    year++;
                }
            }

            else
                day++;
        }

        if(month == 2)

        {
            if(day == 28)

            {
                month++;
                day = 1;
            }

            else
                day++;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Takes the year, month and day and displays it as m/d/yyyy
     * Before it does it though, it changes all the ints to strings 
     */
    private String toString(int yearString, int monthString, int dayString)
    {

        stringDate = (Integer.toString(monthString) + "/" + Integer.toString(dayString)
                + "/" + Integer.toString(yearString));

        return stringDate;
    }

}
```

What I am wondering about is all the || statements are actually correct or if there is a way that requires much less work. I am also fairly new to java and was wondering what was the best possible way to text this in the Eclipse environment.

Comment: There are other ways of doing equality checks like that. 
`Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12).contains(month);`.

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel? Use Joda Time... (And no, your current code isn't correct. Your check for `month` being 12 should be for 13 instead, as it's after the increment.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Do you believe Joda Time is absolutely necessary? Surely the OP would able to manage just fine with using a `Calendar` and manipulating the fields.

Comment: @JoshM: Well we don't know exactly what the OP needs to do, but the `Calendar` API is a horrible mess. Joda Time is *much* cleaner. If there's any non-trivial date/time work involved, I'd take Joda Time in a shot.

Comment: From what I know about Java in classes that I have taken, nothing has been said about the Calander API or Joda Time but seem to be the best way to go about solving this problem.

Comment: There is a trade-of in using libraries, and thus a threshold of doing so. For the absolute most trivial you may not want the ballast of a library. But reality teaches that the vast majority of "absolute most trivial" things have a way of growing beyond that initial qualification, and you'll end up being better off with the better library. What if, some day, you end up being in fact interested in those leap days?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using Calendar?

`Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();`

`time.add(Calendar.DAY,+1)`